# changing from function based view to class based view in Django

Tags: python, comparative-review, django

This is my attempt to convert my password reset function based view to a class based view. Please suggest improvements.

This is my function based view

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import password_reset, password_reset_confirm

def reset(request):
    return password_reset(request, template_name='login/reset.html',
        email_template_name='login/reset_email.html',
        subject_template_name='login/reset_subject.txt',
        post_reset_redirect=reverse('success'))
```

TO change this view to the class based view I have to written this

```
class ResetPassword(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return password_reset(self.request, template_name='login/reset.html',
            email_template_name='login/reset_email.html',
            subject_template_name='login/reset_subject.txt',
            post_reset_redirect=reverse('success'))
    def post(self, request):
        return password_reset(self.request, template_name='login/reset.html',
        email_template_name='login/reset_email.html',
        subject_template_name='login/reset_subject.txt',
        post_reset_redirect=reverse('success'))
```

Comment: Where's `password_reset()` defined?

Comment: from django.contrib.auth.views import password_reset, password_reset_confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both the functions are performing same action, you can just say `post = get`:

```
class ResetPassword(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return password_reset(self.request, template_name='login/reset.html',
            email_template_name='login/reset_email.html',
            subject_template_name='login/reset_subject.txt',
            post_reset_redirect=reverse('success')
        )
    post = get
```